# How to convert warnings on iOS for "may not respond to XXX" warnings into error?

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

When i don't define functions in headers, i get this warning on iOS (as normally). However, i would like the compiler to stop compiling and give me error for this one, so i can find it quickly.

Is there a configuration to convert this type of warning into an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that eventhough other warnings have a code or identifier. This type of warning has not. Therefore it is not possible to convert "ONLY" this warning to error. ( while keeping other warnings as warnings )

Answer (score 3):

You can ask Xcode to treat all warnings as erros, as it's explained in [this blog post](http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/treat-warnings-as-errors.html).

Comment: +1 Technically this doesn't really answer the question but I'm a huge believer in warning free builds. It's saved me many times.